# protobuf-net multiple derived contracts

Tags: c#, protobuf-net, protocol-buffers

I have the following base class:

```
[ProtoContract]
public class Packet
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

This class will be derived by 10+ other classes. My question is how should I assign ProtoInclude attributes?

Is this a good solution or not?

```
[ProtoContract]
[ProtoInclude(20, typeof(NotifyClientBalance))]
[ProtoInclude(21, typeof(IsAlive))]
[ProtoInclude(22, typeof(TransactionConfirmation))]
...
public class Packet
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

Is there a better alternative? How should I assign tags to ProtoInclude? Everything's unclear for me and there's not a good documentation on the matter.

Thanks

P.S.

Is ProtoInclude portable across different platforms? I'm interested in Python in particular.

Thanks again :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For use within protobuf-net, that approach is fine. The numbers are nice and low, which keeps it efficient.

Inheritance is not part of the protobuf specification, so no this is not portable between platforms - at least, not as inheritance. It is portable in terms of getting the data back. It maps to something like:

```
message Packet {
    optional int id = 1;
    optional NotifyClientBalance balance = 20;
    // ...
}
message NotifyClientBalance {...}
//...
```

Or just use `Serializer.GetProto<T>()` to export the schema as .proto